# Initializing jquery tablesorter plugin

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

This is my first attempt at using the jquery library so I am not sure how to initialize the tablesort plugin. I am attempting this without an external .js file so that I know that the link between my html and javascript is not the issue. I have also included a seperate js function so that I know that the jquery library is being loaded. When I click the link I receive the Hello World! alert. I have read and watched about 5 tutorials which explain very well, and without variation, how to do this and each time I get no response when trying to sort my table. Again, for simplicity I have placed my html file, my jquery library and the tablesorter files in the same folder. (see image below)

Here is my code:

```
<html>                                                                  
<head>                                                                  
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js" </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">                                         
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").click(function() {
            alert("Hello world!");
            });
        });

         $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#large").tablesorter();
         });
</script> 
 </head>                                                                 
 <body>   
 <a href="http://localhost/fortesting.html">Link</a>

<table id="large" cellspacing="0">
<thead>

    <tr>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Ip</th>
        <th>Url</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>ISO Date</th>
        <th>UK Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>    
<tbody>
    <tr>

        <td>devo@flexomat.com</td>
        <td>66672</td>
        <td>941-964-8535</td>
        <td>$2482.79</td>
        <td>172.78.200.124</td>
        <td>http://gmail.com</td>
        <td>15:10</td>
        <td>1988/12/14</td>
        <td>14/12/1988</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>henry@mountdev.net</td>
        <td>35889</td>
        <td>941-964-9543</td>
        <td>$2776.09</td>
        <td>119.232.182.142</td>
        <td>http://www.gmail.com</td>
        <td>3:54</td>
        <td>1974/1/19</td>
        <td>19/1/1974</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>christian@reno.gov</td>
        <td>60021</td>
        <td>941-964-5617</td>
        <td>$2743.41</td>
        <td>167.209.64.181</td>
        <td>http://www.dotnet.ca</td>
        <td>10:58</td>
        <td>2000/3/25</td>
        <td>25/3/2000</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Is anyone able to see where my error may be? As far as I can tell it is something to do with the  jquery.tablesorter.min.js file linking to my jquery library but as I mentioned before I have followed multiple tutorials with no change in the outcome. I have attempted this in both IE9 and Firefox. Thanks for taking a look.

[image: shot of my folder]

Comment: Are you getting any errors? your code looks fine. (assuming the missing `>` is a typo since you are getting the alert)

Comment: @Kevin I'm not sure that the missing `>` would negate the alert. I'll put $1 on it actually being the problem.

Comment: @Kevin Wow! that was it. Thanks! And no, I wasn't receiving any errors. The change in color because of the missing `>` was not displaying in my notepad++ so it took posting it here anyway. Not sure why the alert is working without it. Thanks again!

Comment: Why are you calling $(document).ready() twice ?

Comment: @jerome because I have never used jquery before and very literally followed the tutorials.

Comment: @altesv No worries, you don't need to call $(document).ready twice, you can just add your code into this function, so you're sure that the DOM is fully loaded before doing anything. Hope that makes sense, just learn more here : http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing a `>` in your code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js" </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
```

The reason it still works is because it ignores `</script` and then the entire next line up until `</script>`, so essentially it was turned into:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

meaning the tablesorter.js wasn't being loaded.

You should have still been getting a `tablesorter is undefined` error though.

Comment: Thanks for your help Kevin. I'll have to watch closer in the future.